# how to split tests when writing integration test in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutter-integration-test

I'm trying to write an integration test with flutter.
In some cases I need to repeat the same process.
such as adding a new line
I want to make these new line insertion codes as a separate method and call them wherever I want in the test.
but I couldn't find how to do

How can I make some test lines a method in the integration test and call it like a method in the test case I want?

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution i was looking for:

```
class HomeRobot {
  const HomeRobot(this.tester);
  final WidgetTester tester;
  Future<void> findTitle() async {}
  Future<void> scrollThePage({bool scrollUp = false}) async {}           
  Future<void> clickFirstButton() async {}
  Future<void> clickSecondButton() async {}
}
```

https://medium.com/flutter-community/integration-testing-in-flutter-b25c62ec287c